# Accessibility API - Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Is there any way (I think using the Accessibility API) to be able to press a button/keystroke in my app and then hover over a menubar item and press again and then return the name of the menu item, the menu it's in and the app?

I want to do this in Cocoa/Objective-C (Mac).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the `kAXMenuItemSelectedNotification` notification is for.  An easy way to play with this stuff is using [UI Browser](http://pfiddlesoft.com/uibrowser/):

- Pick an application in the "Target" popup menu.
- Pick "Notifications" from the "Drawer" popup menu.
- Click "menu item selected" and "Register" (or just double-click in the table).
- Choose "Notification Log" from the View menu.
- Switch to the application you chose and pick a menu item.

That lets you see when notifications are triggered.  Your code could look something like this:

```
AXError err;
AXObserverRef observer;

pid_t currentAppPID = [NSRunningApplication currentApplication].processIdentifier;
if ( (err = AXObserverCreate(currentAppPID, notificationCallback, &observer) != kAXErrorSuccess); // XXX failed

CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), AXObserverGetRunLoopSource(observer), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);

AXUIElementRef element = AXUIElementCreateApplication(currentAppPID);
if (element == NULL); // XXX failed
if ( (err = AXObserverAddNotification(observer, element, kAXMenuItemSelectedNotification, NULL)) != kAXErrorSuccess); // XXX failed
```

Note that you'll have to observe every running app individually (and additional apps as they launch/quit), or register for `NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification` and deregister/register with the frontmost app at that point (the latter is probably easiest under 10.6 because you get a `NSRunningApplication` as part of the notification).

I would think actually selecting the item would be easier for a user, but if you really do want to press another key to complete the action, you can observe `kAXSelectedChildrenChanged`, which will be triggered when the selection moves from one menu item to another.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you... I registered in the "DidFinishLaunching" :  [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(mySelector:) name:NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification object:nil]; and I put your code in my selector.. - (void)mySelector:(NSNotification*)note is that right?

Comment: I get 2 errors: "Notificationcallback undeclared" and "expected expression before '}' "

Comment: I don't understand you.. what's a callback? how?

Comment: It's a function (signature specified by a typedef, in this case `AXObserverCallback`) that gets invoked when the notification triggers.  See the docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Accessibility/Reference/AccessibilityLowlevel/AXUIElement_h/CompositePage.html%23//apple_ref/c/func/AXObserverCreate